# Exchange 2016 x Cannon scan - Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering - sometimes

Tags: pdf, exchange, spam-prevention

I am running Exchange 2016 and I am facing a trouble with scanned emails from Cannon scanner.

Emails from customers scanner with scanned pdf file are blocked by my exchange

550 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering

but only sometimes. The email comes when PDF file contains more pages and the file is bigger. If the PDF have only one page it is blocked.

I have whitelisted scanner address via management shell
BypassedSenders                       : {scanner@email.com}
which lead only to that scans are no longer transferred into Junkmail folder.

Any tips how to whitelist the address more please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could run the command below to configure all senders in the domain contoso.com and all subdomains aren't checked by content filtering.

Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenderDomains *.contoso.com

Comment: That was done for specific mailbox and unfortunately does not work  BypassedSenders : {scanner@email.com}